# Having Paint loop trouble in java

Tags: java, swing, loops, paintcomponent

For whatever the reason, my loops do not seem to be printing the colors correctly. I have my colors set up before my fills and draws but it isn't showing up the Color.white at all. It is showing white. To better explain what i want the picture to look like ill attach a photo. Thank for any help!

[image]

***This is my ExampleGUI.java source code***

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class ExampleGUI {
public static void main(String args []) {


    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example Graphics");
    ExamplePanel panel = new ExamplePanel();

    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
}
```

***This is my ExamplePanel.java source code***

```
  import java.awt.*;

  import javax.swing.*;


public class ExamplePanel extends JPanel{

public ExamplePanel() {
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension (600, 600));
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);


    int x = 0;
    int x2 = 5;
    int y = 500;
    int y2 = 505;
    int w = 100;
    int w2 = 90;
    int h = 100;
    int h2 = 90;
    int i, j;

    for(j = 1; j < 7; j++) {
        x = 0;
        x2 = x + 5;

        for(i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
            if(i % 2 == 0) {
                g.setColor(Color.white);
                g.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
                g.setColor(Color.black);
                g.drawRect(x, y, w, h);
                g.setColor(Color.green);
                g.fillOval(x2, y2, w2, h2);
                g.setColor(Color.black);
                g.drawOval(x2, y2, w2, h2);

            }else if (i % 2 == 1 && j % 2 == 1)
                    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
                    g.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
                    g.setColor(Color.black);
                    g.drawRect(x, y, w, h);
                    g.setColor(Color.green);
                    g.fillOval(x2, y2, w2, h2);
                    g.setColor(Color.black);
                    g.drawOval(x2, y2, w2, h2);

            x = x + w;
            x2 = x2 + w2 + 10;


        }

        x = x + w;

        y = y - h;
        y2 = (y2 - h2) - 10;
    }


}
}
```

Comment: Your logic is all over the place.  First, use the `if` statements to define the colors you want to use, don't replicate the paint code if you can. Second using something like `if ((i + j) % 2 == 0) {` instead of `if(i % 2 == 0) {` and remove the `else if` and replace it with a `else` instead, that should get a step closer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets start by removing the duplication, for example, instead of...

```
if (i % 2 == 0) {
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawRect(x, y, w, h);
    g.setColor(Color.green);
    g.fillOval(x2, y2, w2, h2);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawOval(x2, y2, w2, h2);

} else if (i % 2 == 1 && j % 2 == 1) {
    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
}
g.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
g.setColor(Color.black);
g.drawRect(x, y, w, h);
g.setColor(Color.green);
g.fillOval(x2, y2, w2, h2);
g.setColor(Color.black);
g.drawOval(x2, y2, w2, h2);
```

You really only need...

```
if (i % 2 == 0) {
    g.setColor(Color.white);
} else if (i % 2 == 1 && j % 2 == 1) {
    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
}
g.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
g.setColor(Color.black);
g.drawRect(x, y, w, h);
g.setColor(Color.green);
g.fillOval(x2, y2, w2, h2);
g.setColor(Color.black);
g.drawOval(x2, y2, w2, h2);
```

Anything you did in the first `if` statement is getting wiped out by the other paint code outside of the `if-else` block...

Next, your logic is slightly off, instead of...

```
if (i % 2 == 0) {
    g.setColor(Color.white);
} else if (i % 2 == 1 && j % 2 == 1) {
    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
}
```

You could use something more like...

```
if ((i + j) % 2 == 0) {
    g.setColor(Color.white);
} else {
    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
}
```

This will get you the checker board look you're after.

[image: Test]

Step closer.  You will need another `for-loop` to generate the inner circles, try not to directly modify the values you are currenly relying on though ;)

You could also use the `if` block to define the background and foreground colors you need to use, assign them to some variables and apply them within the paint section, this will give you more flexibility

Comment: Thank very much! Time to figure out the circles xD

Comment: Remember, painting is fun, more so at 2am!

Comment: That's funny because it was so late when i posted this question xD

Comment: By the way i know the what the for loop needs to look like in this program but i can't seem to figure out where to place it. This is the loop i have so far- for(i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
   g.setColor(Color.black);
   g.drawOval(x, y, w, h);
   x = x + 5;
   y = y + 5;
   w = w - 10;
   h = h - 10;
  }

any ideas :3?

Comment: You need to place it within the two loops, right after you have drawn the first, outer circle...